# How to automate basic ddl scripts execution and management

Tags: mysql, oracle, optimization, automation

Looking for suggestions (A Script, third party tool, software etc.) which can help automate some of the administration tasks around execution of DDL scripts across environments. Database is usually Oracle and MySql

Problem statement: Adding a new column via ALTER TABLE to an existing table. Current process is to send the script to pool of DBAs who get hundreds of such requests from various venues daily. Have to wait for them to pick up the request and then respond which usually takes a day or two. They have to manage that script going forward and execute it in Dev, QA(multiple QA environments) & ultimately PROD. In this process the script is usually lost after PROD and cannot be traced back as to who and why they created a change.

Looking for: Suggestions on how this can be automated. Are there any standard tools or software which can manage scripts across environments. Database is Oracle and MySql.

Comment: This is more about change management than databases.

Comment: Strange environment -- a hundred machines with the same schema and more than a couple of DBAs maintaining them.  At least that is a decent ratio for MySQL.

Comment: Automation tools: Flyway;Datical;Liquibase. Helpful link to a similar relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760629/why-and-when-liquibase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Development Life-cycle requires at least:

- A Code Repository (eg Git) to store your `CREATE TABLE` scripts
- Some tool (eg Liquibase) to auto-generate the `ALTER TABLE` scripts
- Unit Testing tools (SQL Developer has one built in)
- DevOps framework (eg Azure DevOps) to automate

  - the build up of QA/TEST environment
  - deploy scripts to QA/TEST
  - run Unit Test on Test
  - deploy scripts to prod

A [future version of Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/01/19-x-sqlcl-teaser-liquibase/) might include Liquibase.

Comment: Thank you. And yes I understand SDLC. Liquibase is what I was looking for. Datical tool - The parent for Liquibase aligns more with my automation needs. 

Another Stackoverflow questions which may help anyone looking for same info is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760629/why-and-when-liquibase

.Alternate to both of theses tools is - 'Flyway', you can just google it.